# Android app not working in Reliance JIO 4G connection

Tags: permissions

I have an android app which is working completely fine in WiFi and 3G connection.

However, I have found that the app is not connecting to my web-services when Reliance JIO 4G connection is used.

With the same connection, when I open my webservices in Google Chrome, it works fine(slightly slower than other networks).

What could be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem.

First sign up on the MyJIO app.
Then restart your device.
This did the trick for me.